# Restarting Teambox Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running [Teambox](http://teambox.com) (a Ruby on Rails app) and have the server running with:

script/server -e production

Knowing absolutely nothing about Ruby on Rails I just wandered how I could restart the server to get it to update changes I've made to the config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ran it with that command line it's probably running actively in the console, just CTRL+C.

If you ran it daemonize you will need to find the process and kill it.